# Python Date issue when starting a new month

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

I have an issue with a python request. In this request I need to set two dates, today and yesterday. This has functioned without issue throughout my testing until today.

The issue here being that of course we have just started a new month.

I am currently using the following date codes, however as i have now realized they do not take the monthly reset into consideration.

```
yesterday = str(datetime.datetime.today().month) + "/" + 
str(datetime.datetime.today().day-1) + "/" + 
str(datetime.datetime.today().year)

today = str(datetime.datetime.today().month) + "/" + 
str(datetime.datetime.today().day) + "/" + 
str(datetime.datetime.today().year)
```

As soon as the date is not 0 the application works like a charm.

Comment: Dates are neither strings nor ints, they are dates - and calculations on dates are really tricky, so why trying to reinvent the proverbial squared wheel when there are tested libraries already ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `datetime.timedelta`

**Ex:**

```
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.now()
print(today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
yesterday = (today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
print(yesterday)
```

**Output:**

```
10/01/2018
09/30/2018
```

- Use `strftime` to get your required date format in string

Comment: Thank you for the quick and easy to understand reply :)

Answer (score 3):

You make things too complicated, instead of worrying about "wrap arounds", etc.  In your code you subtract the number of days with `1`, but if we are the first of the month (for example *October, 1st*), then by subtracting one from it, we get "October 0th" (sic.).

You better perform the arithmetic *on the `date` object*:

```
yesterday_date = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timestamp(days=1)
```

and then convert it to a string with:

```
yesterday = yesterday_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

At the moment of writing, this generates:

```
>>> yesterday_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
'09/30/2018'
```

Performing arithmetic in the printing is giving "two responsibilities at once", and this is typically *bad software design*: the idea is *one responsibility*.